# SQL 2005 SSIS and Package

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssis

If I have a SSIS Package created in VS 2005 and asked to install and setup this package. Does the server that is going to run this SSIS package have to have SSIS installed? I am 99% sure this is yes, since when I run dtexec /DT packagepath it advises this server does not have SSIS service to run this. Is this correct?

If so, is it best to have one SSIS server to run all packages or install SSIS on the servers that are going to have SSIS packages ran from them?

TY

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, if you are going to run packages then the server must have Integration Services installed on it.
2. You can have one master server that will run all of your packages so long as connections can be made to the servers where the databases, filesystems, etc exist.  If you are going to have multiple servers that run packages then, again, you have to install Integration Services on each of them.

Comment: It is usually less confusing to have the SSIS installed on the same server with the jobs, tables, etc.  If you only have ONE place for packages, that could work, but if there are multiple places to look, and they aren't the same server, that can get ugly.

Comment: SSIS service is not required to run packages.

Answer (score 0):

The SSIS service is not required to run a package stored in the filesystem, if that's what you're asking:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137731.aspx

"The Integration Services service is not required if you only want to design and execute Integration Services packages. However, the service is required to list and monitor packages using SQL Server Management Studio."

Not sure if the DTS folder is installed with a database only install of SQL though...

Since you say that you can run the DTEXEC command it looks like it is installed with shared components perhaps.